# Codeigniter v4.1.4 Advanced Encryption Standard algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption, documentation, codeigniter-4

Here's the problem i'm trying to use the algorithm and have followed the instruction

This is my code in config/encryption.php
[image]

this is my public function commit in controller, along with the library encrypter
[image]

And this the error, caused by emptying public key in config/encryption.php
[image]

what i don't get, isn't that the program: $key = \CodeIgniter\Encryption\Encryption::createKey(); should have created the key for encryption? i have placed that program in config/encryption.php, just like the instruction told me to, is there something i miss? why it didn't want to create a key?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

frist rename env file

```
env
```

to (add dot)

```
.env
```

replace this one with

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENCRYPTION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

 encryption.key ='Zq5t7w!z%C*F-eThWmZq4t7w!z%C&F)J@NcRfUjXn2r5u'
 encryption.driver = OpenSSL
 encryption.blockSize = 16
 encryption.digest = SHA512
```

then

```
$encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter();
$en$encrypter->encrypt("ites");
```

more

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html